# Show text next to marker in Here-Map Android sdk.

Tags: android, here-api

I use HereMap on my android app. I am able to plot markers over the map but not able to show text next to markers. Already tried using setTitle and MapLabeledMarker but these do not seem to be working. 
How can we show some text next to markers plotted on the map in HereMap Android sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to implement this is to use a regular android view layout, inflate it and draw to a bitmap via Canvas APIs. Use the bitmap as the image of the marker as needed.

This provides the best performance as the graphics engine will cache the bitmap you provide and use hardware acceleration to render it.

Comment: I implemented it this way and it worked. But issue with this approach is marker becomes too large. Suppose I was using a pin image to pin-point a particular location, after doing this, marker itself becomes too large to pin-point a location. Any solution to deal with this is highly appreciated?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you mean by too large ? Image width and height can be modified using the Bitmap methods.

Comment: Before adding text next to marker, marker was pointing a particular location and image used is like this [link] (https://lh4.ggpht.com/Tr5sntMif9qOPrKV_UVl7K8A_V3xQDgA7Sw_qweLUFlg76d_vGFA7q1xIKZ6IcmeGqg=w300). After adding text, whole marker image becomes around 100dp in width which no longer able to pin-point the location correctly. The pin-point of image moves as we zoom-in or out the map because its the mid of bitmap (image plus text) that points to location now. What I expect is, only image should point to my location irrespective how long the text is. I hope it clarifies my problem.

Comment: You can change the anchor position of the marker to the tip of the pin? Most likely that would be the middle of the bottom of the image?

Comment: You can also change the image depending on the zoom level. Use the MapRenderListener callbacks to get the zoom level and adjust the image accordingly.

Comment: Thanks DavidLeong and @Teriblus you suggestions did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

MapLabeledMarker is working but does not provide enough control on the rendering and sometimes the text is hidden for some reason (over an other marker, a road element, etc.)

I'm adressing this issue by adding two markers, one for the image and one for the text. I'm drawing the text in a bitmap using android.graphics.Paint.

This is probably worse for performance than David Leong solution but it provides a way to hide the text for lower zoom level using the  MapObject.setVisibleMask method.

Comment: I will try to do it this way also. Maybe the problem I addressed with other solution given by David can be overcome with this approach.